# DataSet Displayed different result than Actual Result from SQL .why?

Tags: asp.net

In WebApplication using VB.Net,I have used Stored Procedure for validation including Duplicate Checking and displayed all those Validation message in a table.While getting that table values in a Dataset,it displayed different result than Actual Result from SQL.

i.e, It displayed "Duplicate record available" even though the Data doesn't have any duplicate value.

When I execute that Profiler Query in SQL, Resultset doesn't contain the "Duplicate record available" record. but in Dataset it contain "Duplicate record available" record in the Table

Comment: You need to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are dealing with post back data. You may be displaying the data twice. Make sure you are clearing out your data that was previously displayed on playback before displaying the current data being returned. Also, please post your code so we can see exactly what is happening.